# Download ASP.NET MVC reference and integrate it with local MSDN Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msdn

Is there a way to download ASP.NET MVC reference and make it available through the local MSDN library?

I am tired of going to Microsoft's site everytime I need a simple class or method documentation reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an official download yet - but you can get an unofficial download using the [PackageThis](http://www.codeplex.com/packagethis), which connects to the MSDN Content Service, pulls the data down and builds local CHM or HXS files for you.

Answer (score 2):

Not answering your question, but did you know that the online MSDN library is now available in ["loband" format](http://blogs.msdn.com/innovation/archive/2009/03/26/launching-low-bandwidth-loband-beta-for-long-haul.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new version of this software [PackageThis!](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/626677ab-c35f-4f3d-9f7c-6b471b1195dd) available at Visual Studio Gallery, which supports Mshc file format (Visual Studio 2010/2012 help packages).